# ios Facebook Login not working;

Tags: facebook-login

```
Sandbox Mode=on   
Bundle ID =same FBid=Ok ..Anything else does not matter  

-(void) askForPublishPermission
{ BOOL isSessionActive = [self isFacebookSessionActive];
//BOOL useUI = !isSessionActive;
//useUI = YES;
BOOL publishPermissionAvailable = NO;

if (isSessionActive)
{
    NSArray* validPermission = [[FBSession activeSession] permissions];


    for (int i=0; i<[validPermission count]; i++)
    {
        NSObject* permission = [validPermission objectAtIndex:i];

        if ([permission isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
        {
            NSString* validPermission = (NSString*)permission;
            //NSLog(@"Valid Permissions = %@", validPermission);
            if ([validPermission isEqualToString:@"publish_actions"])
            {
                publishPermissionAvailable = YES;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

if (publishPermissionAvailable == YES)
{
    //NSLog(@"------------------ CALL AT TWO --------------");
    //NSLog(@"Login Success");
}
else // Request for publish permission.
{
    NSArray* permissionArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
                                @"publish_actions",nil];
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:permissionArray
                                       defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone
                                          allowLoginUI:YES
                                     completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                         FBSessionState state,
                                                         NSError *error) {
                                         [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                             state:state
                                                             error:error];
                                     }];



  }
}
```

and

```
-(void) askForPublishPermission
{
BOOL isSessionActive = [self isFacebookSessionActive];
//BOOL useUI = !isSessionActive;

//useUI = YES;
BOOL publishPermissionAvailable = NO;

if (isSessionActive)
{
    NSArray* validPermission = [[FBSession activeSession] permissions];


    for (int i=0; i<[validPermission count]; i++)
    {
        NSObject* permission = [validPermission objectAtIndex:i];

        if ([permission isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
        {
            NSString* validPermission = (NSString*)permission;
            //NSLog(@"Valid Permissions = %@", validPermission);
            if ([validPermission isEqualToString:@"publish_actions"])
            {
                publishPermissionAvailable = YES;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

if (publishPermissionAvailable == YES)
{
    //NSLog(@"------------------ CALL AT TWO --------------");
    //NSLog(@"Login Success");
}
else // Request for publish permission.
{
    NSArray* permissionArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
                                @"publish_actions",nil];
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:permissionArray
                                       defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone
                                          allowLoginUI:YES
                                     completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                         FBSessionState state,
                                                         NSError *error) {
                                         [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                             state:state
                                                             error:error];
                                     }];



  }
}
```

But ..Not login..

error code see below:

```
Error = Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.){com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason=com.facebook.sdk:SystemLoginCancelled, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorInnerErrorKey=Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 "The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: The app must ask for a basic read permission  like email at install time."
```

I'd spent a few months this issue..Please Help me

Answer (score 0):

Your error message says:

> The app must ask for a basic read permission  like email at install time.

From [the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/login-tutorial#button-permissions):

> When someone connects with an app using Facebook login, the app can access their public profile and friend list, the pieces of information that are visible to everyone. To create this basic connection, apps must **always** request access to a person's basic profile information by asking for the `basic_info` permission.

Try adding `basic_info` to `permissionArray` array. If that doesn't work, try adding `email` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced :

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"] defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:stateHandler];
```

with

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:@[@"basic_info", @"publish_actions", @"email"] defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:stateHandler];
```

And now it's working

(permissions orders matter, `basic_info` have to be in first position)